# Exclude weekends

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to calculate the days between two different dates.  If d1 is on saturday or sunday it should not take calculate those days.  d2 is the system date.

the formula i have is

```
(ROUND((d2-d1)-DECODE(SIGN(TO_CHAR(d2,'D')-        
TO_CHAR(d1,'D')),-1,2,0)+DECODE(TO_CHAR(d1,'D'),7,1,0)-
DECODE(TO_CHAR(d2,'D'),7,1,0),2)) AS "DAYS",
```

this would give me 1 days from friday to sunday which is correct, but 7 days from sunday to last sunday instead of 5.  anyway i can improve on this formula, or is there a simpler one i can use?